# JUnit - string check fails because of \n

Tags: java, string, testing, junit, console

I have a JUnit test case where text blocks are checked. There is the hard coded "correct" value:

```
String CORRECT_VAL = "First\\nSecond";
```

The json is generated like this:

```
String json =
            "{\n" +
            "    \"val\":\"" + CORRECT_VAL + "\",\n" +
            "}";
```

This String is converted to a JSONObject by org.json. But then the test failed:

```
expected:<First[\r\n]Second> but was:<First[
]Second>
```

So I see the "\n" in the console, too. :(

---

**Comment Try 1":**

```
expected:<First\[\]nSecond> but was:<First\[]nSecond>
Expected :First\\nSecond
Actual   :First\nSecond
```

**Comment Try 2":**

```
expected:<First[\r\n]Second> but was:<First[
]Second>
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the escape slash?  `"First\\\\nSecond"`

Comment: @Parris Varney: For result see question.

Answer (score 2):

`\` is a special symbol that is used to mark certain special characters:

`\n` will be translated into a line break, for example.

`\\` means escaping the backslash, so it will be transformed into a single backslash. As one backslash is a special symbol, you need to do this if you want to write an actual backslash in your java code. (The whole thing does NOT happen when reading from a file, just when writing it in your code).

`\\n` means "a backslash, followed by a 'n'", literally. No line breaks there.

So, you either have to ask for the correct character in your result or write the correct character in your json. At the moment, you are comparing "`\n`" (line break) with "`\\n`" (backslash, followed by a n). Or, in your other example, "`\n`" (line break) with "`\\\\n`" (two backslashes, followed by an n).

What your message is telling you is, that you are doing this check:

```
 Assert.assertEquals("First\\r\\nSecond", "First\r\nSecond");
```

... or perhaps this...

```
 Assert.assertEquals("First\\r\\nSecond", "First\nSecond");
```

In other words, the expected string has "\r\n" (FOUR characters), while the actual String has some kind of actual line break, for example '\r' + '\n' (cariage return,  followed by line break) (TWO characters).

You are expecting the TEXT, literally "\r\n". But what you GET is probably the SYMBOL which is represented by '\r' followed by the symbol '\n', which will result in an actual line break.

Comment: The JSON is an example of a database result. So how do I have to store linebreaks in the database, so that the test works?

Comment: The expected value `\r\n` does not fit what you are writing, sorry. That's not `\\n`. Also '\\n' is not a line break, so it also isn't the axctual value. Something is not as you quoted here. I don't know WHAT is actually stored in your database. Line breaks can be stored in various formats (Windows, Unix, escaped, not escaped, etc.) so it's hard to say. I would check what the output from the database actually is (perhaps by printing out the code of every character).

Comment: I have checked it. I am using HeidiSQL and it inserts a linebreak with `\r\n`.

Comment: If it uses the two characters '\r' and '\n', then that is what you should check for.

Comment: Updated question. As you can see, parsing the data to a json string, then to a jsonobject and then to a string, it replaces \r\n by its correct meaning. So the result is correct, if I wwill print the string from the json object out. But JUnit thinks its wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

I had created the json string in the test class itself, so I used `First\\nSecond` because the `\n` has to be escaped in the json string.

But I also checked that the result is `First\\nSecond`, but this is wrong.

**Insert in JSON: `First\\nSecond`

Check against: `First\nSecond`**

**Use commons-lang3:**
`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("First\\nSecond").equals(jsono.getString("key"));`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with **\r** and not **\n**. I too faced similar issues while working on Test cases.